# Constructing JSON with a number as an attribute name

Tags: json, xml, xquery, informatica, informatica-cloud

The following problem is happening inside of Informatica CAI. Here I only have access to Xquery to edit variables and construct data.

I am attempting to map a JSON's attribute names into numbers. A readable example of this problem is a input/temp/output variable $json

being equal to

```
{
   "Person":
   {
      "Name": "Jerry",
      "Age": "42"
   }
}
```

and a temp variable $MapTable

```
{
   "Name": "3456_1",
   "Age": "3456_2"
}
```

When attempting to map the numbers from $MapTable to take the place of "Name" and "Age" in $json with Xquery, I receive a
"Invalid element name. Invalid QName {3456_1}" error." I believe this is due to XML name regulations.

Does anyone know of a way around this so I can end up with $json being equal to

```
{
   "Person":
   {
       "3456_1": "Jerry",
       "3456_2": "42"
   }
}
```

Note: I've posted the same question on Informatica's Cloud Application Integration Forum.

Comment: Exactly, QName cannot start with a number, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/QName

Comment: Have you tried `declare option output:method "json";`?

Comment: Hi Pavel, this expression does not validate successful when I write it in above my xquery, e.g.:

declare option output:method "json";
for $x in $input.JSON/node()
return
element
{fn:node-name($x)}{5}

Do I need to define or import something else? Or perhaps add the declaration elsewhere?

Comment: Try to return a string instead of element.

Comment: A solution using the fn:replace solved the problem.

Comment: @JosephKnutson Please post a more detailed (reproducible) answer to the question using the answer box below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ending up with the correct json attribute names, I can use xquery to produce a json such as this
{
"Person":
{
"__3456_1": "Jerry",
"__3456_2": "42"
}
}
The double underscore prefix allows informatica to not crash. Then we can use the function "fn:replace" on the variable holding the json to remove he double underscore: fn:replace("__",""), leaving us with the desired JSON.

It's not a perfect solution to my question, since the script to map from one json to the other lies uncreated still.